# Get/Set in C# easier way?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

Hey so I am currently writing a program for university and when creating my classes I am using get set my question is, is there an easier way than this method shown bellow to set things.

Code snippet showing my current way

```
    private string customer_first_name;
    private string customer_surname;
    private string customer_address;
    public DateTime arrival_time;

//Using accessors to get the private variables
//Using accessors to set the private variables

    public string Customer_First_Name
    {
        get { return customer_first_name; }
        set { customer_first_name = value; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, saves quite a bit of time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) instead:

```
public string Customer_First_Name { get; set; }
```

In this case compiler will generate field for storing property value.

*BTW* you can save even more time if you will use `prop` code snippet in Visual Studio. Just start typing `prop` and hit `Tab` - it will paste snippet for auto-generated property. All what you need - provide property name and type.

Comment: Using `prop` is indeed very handy, also hitting `Tab` after providing the type will cycle to the next marked 'item' this goes for all snippets. Very handy for p.e. `propfull` if you still need a backingfield and certainly handy for `propd` in wpf.

Comment: Works well, but you have any code in your getter/setter or change the access modifiers...you would use other code snippets or manually edit them.

Comment: @BartCzernicki as Silvermind stated, there is `propfull` snippet, which creates property with backing field - saves time

Comment: Hmm...weird I didn't see that comment until now.  My bad, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string Customer_First_Name { get; set; }
```

is sufficient if you don't need any logic in your getter/setter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string Customer_First_Name {get; set;}
```

Doing that will also implicitly create an underlying field for you.

Comment: Well, er, `customer_first_name` will (unless something changed in the spec recently) not be declared, the compiler will generate a field for the value automatically, but not with an accessible name.

Comment: However, in VB this field is accessible but is not revealed by intellisense. It's name is the name of the property prepended by "_".